# What Alt + number is a tick?

Tags: windows-10

I looked up the number on the internet and it said it was Alt + 0252 but this just gives me an ü. What number do you have to type in to get a tick while holding the Alt Key?

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_mark) check mark?

Comment: It depends on the character set you're using. If you want the tick mark that Sonickyle27 has indicated, you'll need to use the Wingdings font. Run up charmap.exe, change the font to Wingdings and scroll to the bottom right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tick mark which you referred to, i.e *Alt + 0252* is only possible if you select the font as "**Wingdings**" as mentioned in this [Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-a-check-mark-symbol-09b3d8e6-cd92-423a-9f5e-7f813e7e4b9e).

The Unicode value depends on the font which is present in the editor which you are using and the tick symbol is not available in normal text fonts other than "**Wingdings**" or similar ones which are symbolic fonts.

Comment: Wow - didn't know that, not really being a Windows user. Frankly, that's a really poor implementation in this day & age :/  ... & U+0252 isn't even a check mark at all, so it totally breaks in unicode.

Comment: @Tetsujin ., I agree , even I found this confusing and inefficient with Alt + value not matching with U+value in all the cases

Comment: So how, for instance, would you insert that character on this page & have it visible to all? In my answer I used the correct unicode value for it - ✓ - does that mean Windows users can't see it? [Just tested from Windows & yes it is shown... which makes it even less consistent.] What would happen if someone posted it using Wingdings?

Comment: Nope , thats not the case , while using Alt+value function , this procedure matters.Once it is inserted , it will be visible on all the platforms with no dependency. its not the implementation of symbols which is wrong for the symbol , rather the procedure employed to insert the symbols is confusing.

Comment: But that symbol doesn't exist in Wingdings on Mac, nor is there any checkmark at all at U+0252, so what is it in fact inserting? I'd love to see one posted in your answer... just so I can see the result. [I'm not questioning *you* btw, merely how Win manages to implement this]

Comment: @Tetsujin,in the character map of Windows , for every font , there are specific set of characters which follow unicode **U+value** format which can be invoked by **Alt+Unicodevalue** , but some of the unicode symbols like these tick marks are not considered as characters, but as symbols and doesnt have a Unicode value ,they have a character value. so this tick can only be found in wingding as a symbol and has character value of 0xFC which is "252" , and can be invoked by **Alt+0<char value in decimals>** which is **Alt+0252**. this will clear us why 0252.

Comment: @Tetsujin, and about why we need wingding , these character values are not unique to all the symbols... symbol number x in one font might have same character code as that of symbol y in other font and thats what we observed which printed wierd characters...so you need to load the specific font if you want a symbol to be used from that .

Comment: That really is "go it alone" madness. Why do we have international standards if MS are going to completely ignore them? Wingdings is just a font, it shouldn't have different numbers to unicode, it ought to correctly map to unicode values, so anybody on an OS with proper font substitution built-in doesn't have to jump through hoops to see what was intended. I'd still love to see it posted in the answer, so I can see what it does substitute to.

Comment: I am afraid I do not have in depth knowledge on the OS to really trace these kind of things and I hope I would have had that..I am just a long term Windows user and can create some logical connections between bits and pieces which I know.

Answer (score 2):

The standard check mark ✓ [yes, the UK calls it a tick, US check] is U+2713
so presumably on Windows that would equate to alt+2713, confirmed by [FileFormat](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm).

Yet when I test it, on an rtf file it generates ઙ & in a txt file Ö - so there appears to be no consistency.

Comment: There is consistency described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code): Alt + number (without leading zero) -> [OEM codepage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page#OEM_code_page) ; Alt + number (with leading zero) -> [Windows 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) ; Alt + [+] + 4 hex digits -> (if Registry enabled `EnableHexNumpad`) Unicode. So the "correct" way to enter ✓ is [Alt] [+] [2] [7] [1] [3] after enable `HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method\EnableHexNumpad`.

Answer (score 2):

By default, windows alt codes point to the ASCII (+ Extended) character map.  So without making any changes to the system, you can use [ALT] [2] [5] [1] to get a √.

Refer to the above answers for required steps to generate a Unicode tick.

Comment: Thank you! This is the correct answer for not fiddling with settings!

Answer (score -1):

If you have enabled the hex code you can do this by entering (hold alt) + 0 2 7 1 3 (release alt).

Note + is the actual plus key.

Comment: This gives me ™